# Email Verification in Laravel 5.1.*

Tags: laravel-5.1

I want to add email verification on my laravel app. Just after submitting the registration form the user will get an email with confirmation link. How can I implement this by using laravel's default auth controller? I have added two fields on my user table (confirmed, confirmation_code). Please someone help me...

Comment: Have you done any research in to this or tried anything? You won't learn anything if we just give you the code - better you try something and we help you debug it to get it working.

Comment: Trying from yesterday bro. This is my last step (to seek help in stackoverflow). All the solutions I got were related to L5, where they use RegisterUser controller, but in laravel 5.1 it's AuthController. I have decided to create a route of sending mail (with confirmation code). Just after submitting the form the user will be redirected to that route. But now I am having problem with sending mail.  Swift_TransportException with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xyz@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators'

Comment: You could place the code to generate a confirmation code and send the email in the `AuthController` itself if you wanted. However it sounds like you have a work around. Regarding the error you get, have you enabled your gmail account to use less secure apps - https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps ? Or do you have two-factor auth on for gmail?

Comment: I tried many ways in gmail (enabled less secure app, unlocked captcha), but didn't work. Just few seconds ago it worked with mailgun (emo of happiness). Thank you for your great support James. I'll let you know how far I have gone with the verification.

Comment: OK perfect. As an example, I'll post an answer to show you how I have achieved email verification from within the `AuthController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our comment thread, here's how you can integrate it in to the `AuthController`. There may be better ways to do this, but it has worked a charm for me.

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
       //Run validator checks....


        $confirmation_code = str_random(30);
        $newUser = new User;
        $newUser->username = $request->username;
        $newUser->email = $request->email;
        $newUser->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $newUser->confirmation_code = $confirmation_code;

        $newUser->save();

        $data = array('confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code);

        Mail::send('emails.verify', $data, function ($message) use ($newUser){
            $message->to($newUser->email, $newUser->username);
                $message->subject('Please verify your email address');
        });

        //Continue on with any other logic
    }
```

Comment: One more thing James... I have added one more field (confirmed) on getCredentials() function of foundation/Auth/AthenticatesUsers.php file. But I couldn't find where I should compare if confirmed == 1 to authenticate the user.

Comment: @musafir is this for when they click on the link to activate their account or for when they are logging in to check their account is confirmed?

Comment: Can please tell me how to add code in the comment :p

Answer (score 0):

It was for when they are in the logged in state. Fortunately I managed to solve this one. I changed my Authenticate middleware like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        } elseif (!\Auth::user()->is_activated()) {
        \Session::flash('message', 'Please activate your account to proceed.');
        return redirect()->guest('/notice/activate');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```